# Pass single value within onClick (without using a form submit)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Rather than creating several putPriority fetches, I'd ideally just like to pass a singular value.

But this value won't be entered via the user (ie not an input field)

I'd like pass this value through an onClick.

In my example, I'd like the onClick to pass a single number to "status" in the fetch (this.state.level).

Basically I want it to work like this:

```
  putPriority: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     return fetch(DATA_API, {
     method: 'PUT',
     body: JSON.stringify({
         status:this.state.level,
         tag:[
           {}
          ]
      })
      })
      .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
      .then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
  },


  ...

  render: function(){
        return (
    <Button onClick={this.putPriority} title="level" value="1">High </Button>

    <Button onClick={this.putPriority} title="level" value="2">Medium </Button>

    <Button onClick={this.putPriority} title="level" value="3">Low </Button>
  }
)};
```

Comment: How is `Button` defined? Can it not just pass the value of `value` when it calls the `onClick` function?

Comment: you can use bind to pass value to click function ... e.g. this.putPriority.bind(this, yourvalue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind()` to pass value to the `handleClick` function and the instead of `this.state.level` just use value liek

```
body: JSON.stringify({
     status:value,
     tag:[
       {}
      ]
  })
```

```js
var App = React.createClass ({
putPriority: function(value, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(value);
  },

  render: function(){
        return (
          <div>
    <button onClick={this.putPriority.bind(this, '1')} title="level" value="1">High </button>

    <button onClick={this.putPriority.bind(this, "2")} title="level" value="2">Medium </button>

    <button onClick={this.putPriority.bind(this, "3")} title="level" value="3">Low </button>
</div>  
)  
}
  
})
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to get current value :

```
putPriority: function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var currentStatus = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("value");
 return fetch(DATA_API, {
 method: 'PUT',
 body: JSON.stringify({
     status: currentStatus,
     tag: [
       {}
      ]
  })
  })
  .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
  .then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
},
```

this will solve your problem

```
var currentStatus = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: `Button` seems to be a custom components. Without more code it's unclear whether an event object is passed to `putPriority`.

Comment: yes you are right but  he is using react and according react syntax "e" will be event and as well he defined e.preventDefault(); so "e" is "event" so we can access its relevant element.

Comment: If we were talking about the `button` HTML element, then yes. But in the code they are using a `Button` **component** (note the capital B vs lowercase b), which we don't know anything about. We don't know what the component is doing with the `onClick` prop.

Comment: yes that is also good point , :) let him define this .. thanks for pointing out that.